# iterating through a list with self parameter

Tags: python, list, class, python-3.x

Trying to iterate through a list with rectangles in them. Then remove/ delete all the rectangles which are orange coloured from the list. I wrote a piece of code for it but keep getting not itterable error.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
root = Tk()
from Stack import Stack
from my_queue import *

class Recta:

  def __init__(self, height=60, width=80 ,colours= []):
    self.height = height
    self.width = width
    self.canvas = Canvas(root)
    self.canvas.pack()
    self.colours = ["red", "orange"]
    self.rects = []
    self.stack = Stack()
    self.queue = Queue()

  def randomRects(self):
    w = random.randrange(300)
    h = random.randrange(200)
    self.rects.append(self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, w, h, fill= random.choice(self.colours)))

  def remove_all_orange_shapes(self):
    for i in self.randomRects():
        if i == "orange": 
          return self.canvas.delete(self.rects.pop())
        else:
          continue 

tes = Recta()
tes= Stack()
tes = Queue()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `randomRects` returns `None` ... so of coarse `for item in None` is not valid python

Comment: You name three object `tes`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ... but proceeds to use none of them ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley, yep, even more food for thought.

Comment: @rprogramr, I would suggest you read a tutorial http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/

Comment: randomRects should return a random shape

Comment: Please learn [ask] and give a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

`randomRects` is creating a list of rectangles, but it is not *returning* a list of rectangles. It is returning the default return value of `None`. When you try to iterate over it (`for i in self.randomRects()`) you are iterating over the value `None`, which will throw an error.

The second problem is that `self.rects` is creating a list of canvas object ids, yet you're comparing the ids to the string "orange" which will never be true. Canvas object ids are numbers.

What you need to do is a) loop over `self.rects`, and b) get the color of the item before doing the comparison. Then, c) delete the canvas item, and d) update `self.rects`

There are several ways to accomplish this. Following is one way. Though, it assumes you've created the random rectangles ahead of time. The way your code was working, you were creating and deleting the rectangles all at the same time.

```
def remove_all_orange_shapes(self):
    new_rects = []
    for i in self.rects:
        color = self.canvas.itemcget(i, "fill")
        if color == "orange": 
            # delete the orange ones ...
            self.canvas.delete(i)
        else:
            # ... and save the non-orange ones
            new_rects.append(i)
    self.rects = new_rects
```